# Jquery: can't seem to get select tag change(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onchange

here is my html:

```
<select class="span12 chzn-select" name="periods" id="periods" data-placeholder="--Please Select--" tabindex="1" style="width: 300px;">
  <opion value="-1">Please Select</option>  
  <option value="1">test option</option>
  <option value="2">test option 2</option>
</select>
```

here is my js:

```
$('#periods').change(function() {
  alert( 'testing' );
});
```

I have no idea why when selecting an option from the select tag, the alert message is not poping up.  Here is jsfiddle.net:

https://jsfiddle.net/b91cp5Lv/

Comment: You didn't include `jquery` in your fiddle.. Here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b91cp5Lv/1/).. Try look at the of your JS Code.. A "JavaScript (jQuery 3.2.1) " is written above.. There you can add the libraries you want to add like jquery..

Comment: @ShadowFiend well done.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your first `<option>` tag

Fixing this on jsfiddle and selecting jquery as an import option seems to work.